# Python: simple divisibility test

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple code that prompts users to enter two numbers to determine whether they are evenly divisible:

```
print 'Enter the following'
num1 = input("Integer:")
num2 = input("Integer:")
evaluation = ((num1 / num 2) / 2)
print num1, "/2", num2, "/2" = ",evaluation
```

I am new to Python and am seeking advice on how to tweak this code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: evenly divisible does not mean that the quotient is divisible by 2. It means that the remainder from dividing one of the numbers with the other is 0

Comment: Do you want to know if both `num1` and `num2` are divisible by 2, or if `num1` is divisible by `num2`?

Comment: @chepner I'd like to know whether num1 is evenly divisible by num2. I'm not sure how to write it so that it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need the [modulo operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)

```
print "Enter the following"
num1 = input("Integer:")
num2 = input("Integer:")
evaluation = num1 % num2
if evaluation == 0:
    print num1, "/", num2, " evenly divides"
else:
   print num1, "/", num2, " does not evenly divide"
```

Comment: you should really use `int(raw_input(...))` but yeah